# How to retrieve data in Django model using related name and generic detail views

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am trying to display the data from one of my models to the DetailView using the related name defined in the model. It works for the Rental Property model but it doesn't work for the contract model. What might seems to be the problem?

A little context to what I am trying to achieve. To get the attribute's value of the rental model, I use a for loop on landlord.rentalproperty.all; rentalproperty been the related name to the landlord model. This work perfectly.

Where I am having a problem is when I use the contract model related name to rentalproperty, this doesn't work. How can I fixed that? Thanks.

my model:

```
UserModel = get_user_model()

class Landlord(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.address)


class RentalProperty(models.Model):
    landlord = models.ForeignKey("Landlord", related_name='rentalproperty', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, related_name='rentalproperty', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    PROPERTY_LISTING_CHOICES = Choices(
        ('APARTMENT', _('Apartment')),
        ('HOLIDAY_HOME', _('Holiday home')),
        ('SINGLE_FAMILY_HOME', _('Single family home')),
        ('COMMERCIAL', _('Commercial')),
    )
    type_of_property_listing = models.CharField(
        max_length = 50,
        choices = PROPERTY_LISTING_CHOICES,
        default = PROPERTY_LISTING_CHOICES.APARTMENT,)

    street = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    borough = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.type_of_property_listing)

class Contract(models.Model):
    rentalproperty = models.ForeignKey("RentalProperty", related_name='contracts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    insurance_required = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    other_terms = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.insurance_required)
```

My html:

```
 <h1>This is the detail view</h1>
    <h3>From landlord</h3>
    <p>Address: {{landlord.address}}</p>
    <h3>From Rental property</h3>
    <ul>
    {% for rental in landlord.rentalproperty.all %}
    <li>landlord: {{rental.landlord}}</li>
    <li>createdby: {{rental.created_by}}</li>
    <li>Type of property: {{rental.type_of_property_listing}}</li>
    <li>Street: {{rental.street}}</li>
    <li>Borough: {{rental.borough}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <ul>
    {% for contract in rentalproperty.contracts.all %}
    <li> rental property: {{contract.rentalproperty}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

My detail View.

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Landlord
    template_name = 'rental/detail.html'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work for the contract model"? `{{contract.rentalproperty}}` will give an object, you may want `{{contract.rentalproperty.get_type_of_property_listing_display }}`. Docs for the `.get_FOO_display()` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

Comment: Thanks @shad0w_wa1k3r. I meant I was able to get the data from the Rental Property model in the templates, but when I use the related name for the contract, It doesn't display to templates. I was following this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/

Comment: Why do you want to get the `contract.rentalproperty`? Wouldn't that be the same as `rentalproperty` already available in your template's context?

Comment: From the model attributes, I can see for example the address from the Landlord model, I can get the street and borough from the RentalProperty model. When I try to display the insurance-_required or other_terms attribute value from the Contract model to the detail templates, I can not see anything using the related name associated to the RentalProperty model. Do you understand what I mean now?

Comment: May I suggest to not use the generic views for something this complex? You should just use [normal view funcitons](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/views/). The generic views are handy only when the logic is quite straight-forward. In the function you can actually build / fetch all the required context data and pass it to the template, so that, if required in debuggin, you can print the data (or check it in django debug toolbar) that you are passing & figure out what / why it's missing.

Comment: Could you post your DetailView?

Comment: I think that is what I should do. Thanks

Comment: @Aerials This is my detail view.

Comment: @superv answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Here's a `DetailView` view:

```py
class RentalPropertyDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'property'
    model = models.RentalProperty
```

*Notice the "context_object_name" attribute.*

Second, your template is a little confusing.. Why would you want to loop for one landlord, listing the landlord's name again for each of its rental properties. And the the same for each contract?

### Here's a`rentalproperty_detail.html` template:

```html
<h1>This is the detail view</h1>
<h3>From landlord: {{ property.created_by }}</h3>
<p>Address: {{ property.landlord.address }}</p>
<h3>From Rental property</h3>
<ul>
    {% for rental in property.landlord.rental_properties.all %}
    <br>
    <li>createdby: {{rental.created_by}}</li>
    <li>Type of property: {{rental.type_of_property_listing}}</li>
    <li>Street: {{rental.street}}</li>
    <li>Borough: {{rental.borough}}</li>
    <ul>
        {% for contract in rental.contracts.all %}
        <li> Insurance required: {{contract.insurance_required}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

### Now a `models.py`:

```py
class RentalProperty(models.Model):
    landlord = models.ForeignKey("Landlord", related_name='rental_properties', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    PROPERTY_LISTING_CHOICES = [
        ('APARTMENT', ('Apartment')),
        ('HOLIDAY_HOME', ('Holiday home')),
        ('SINGLE_FAMILY_HOME', ('Single family home')),
        ('COMMERCIAL', ('Commercial')),
    ]
    type_of_property_listing = models.CharField(
            max_length = 50,
            choices = PROPERTY_LISTING_CHOICES,
            default = 'APARTMENT',
        )

    street = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, null=True)
    borough = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.type_of_property_listing)


class Contract(models.Model):
    rental_property = models.ForeignKey("RentalProperty", related_name='contracts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    insurance_required = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    other_terms = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.insurance_required)
```

The `Landlord` model I left it the same.

### In `urls.py` you should fetch one (1) `RetailProperty` like:

```py
url(r'^property/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.RentalPropertyDetailView.as_view(), name='property-detail'),
```

---

This will output the following:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. That is what I have been looking for. Could you please explain where you get the rental.contracts from and if I what to add another model to the application, how can I use the same related name to get the attribute's value? Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. It's generally not a good idea to name two different objects with the same name, unless they belong to a different namespace

Comment: According to the template, rental comes from the property (the one being detailed in the view)'s landlord's set of properties. So rental is effectively one property belonging to the landlord. And each rental has a set of contracts, hence rental.contracts

Comment: Do you mean the rental from "rental in property.landlord.rentalproperties.all" ? From the detail view,  how can I get a rental post to be in a separate detail view instead of been to added together in just one detail view. For example, if I add another rental post, it will be added to the previous rental detail view instead of a separate detail view.